# Any way to tell a class is from Groovy/Grails or original Java?

Tags: java, grails, logging, groovy, log4j

People using Grails/Groovy should know that when using log4j to log message will happen that the method name and the line number in log message are both wrong.

So I customized my own PatternLayout. PatternLayout, and LocationInfo following this url: [log4j-groovy](http://web.archive.org/web/20100724050702/http://www.kotek.net/projects/log4j-groovy)

However, when a normal java class calls my customized PatternLayout, the method name is wrong.

What I can think the simplest way is to let my PatternLayout to know whether a caller is a Groovy class or a normal Java class so that my PatternLayout can know the way it should approach.

So, is there any way to know a caller (class) is from Groovy or from Java ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

All groovy object implement interface GroovyObject so you could check it via:

```
if (o instanceof GroovyObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could get you close:

```
def isJavaClass = {Class c ->
    def m = c.metaClass.methods.find() { it.name == 'getMetaClass' }

    m == null || m.declaringClass.toString() == 'class groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport'
}

class Blah {
}

def classes = [
    TimeZone, 
    Closure, 
    Blah].findAll { isJavaClass(it) }

assert classes == [TimeZone, Closure]
```

I poked around in the [metaClass](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/MetaClass.html) but couldn't find a fool-proof way to detect Java classes.